# Spring batch with commit-interval 2 writes same object two times and skips the other object

Tags: jdbc, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I have a batch writing data from a file to an Oracle-database using a `FlatFileItemReader` and a `JdbcItemWriter`, both from the Spring Framework. 
When I configure a `commit-interval` > 1, let's say 2, the Reader reads two lines from the file and than the writer writes the data from the second line two times to the database.

My configuration is like this:

```
<batch:job id="Job">
    <batch:step id="step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer"
                commit-interval="2" processor-transactional="false" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:fail on="FAILED" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="Reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <!-- TODO: FilePath definieren (Umgebungsabhängig) -->
    <property name="resource" value="file:in/Users_kurz.csv" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="name1, name2, name3, name4" />
                    <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="lineObject" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
  <bean id="LineObject" class="this.is.my.LineObject" />

 <bean id="dcIdentityWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3, col4)
   VALUES (:name1, name2, name3, name4)" />
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your java code as well such as the code that is reading in the file data and the code that is writing it to the database?

Comment: you need to show `this.is.my.LineObject` code.

Comment: this.is.my.LineObject is like this: public class LineObject { private String name1; private String name2; + getter + setter } The code reading the file and writing to the database are the spring-classes FlatFileItemReader and JdbcBatchItemWriter